# How to send email from firebase admin panel for verify the email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase email verification system to verify the user email. But some of the user can't do that. So that I want to send mail using firebase console. Is there anyway to send email verification mail from firebase console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to trigger email verification from the Firebase console. To reduce abuse, Firebase only supports sending such an email when requested by the already authenticated user in the client-side code itself.

If triggering it from the user's device doesn't work for (some of) your users, the best starting point is to investigate why that doesn't work.